# Cook-Torrance shader cuts off really weird when NdotL <= 0

Tags: opengl, glsl, shading

So i've been trying to implement the Cook-Torrance shader model in a toy project I'm working on and it looks quite good when looking at the right angle:
[image: Normal]
But when you're looking from a shallow angle the visuals you get bright artifacts and around the cutoff.

The cutoff happens because I'm checking if NdotL > 0, but if I remove it things start to become even stranger:
[image: Removed NdotL check]
Colors get inverted, some kind of line emerges where NdotL == 0 and every fragment where NdotH < 0 becomes black, making it have an egg shape.

Here is the shader code:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 camPos;
in vec3 lightDir;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D glossTexture;
uniform sampler2D metalTexture;
uniform samplerCube cubemapTexture;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

float F(float ior, vec3 view, vec3 halfV) {
    float F0 = abs((1.0 - ior) / (1.0 + ior));
    F0 *= F0;
    float VoH = dot(view,halfV);
    float fresnel = F0+(1-F0) * pow(1 - VoH,5);
    return fresnel;
}

float chiGGX(float v) {
    return v > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
float G(vec3 view, vec3 norm, vec3 halfV, float alpha) {
    float VoH2 = clamp(dot(view,halfV),0.0,1.0);
    float chi = chiGGX( VoH2 / clamp(dot(view,norm),0.0,1.0));
    VoH2 = VoH2 * VoH2;
    float tan2 = (1-VoH2) / VoH2;
    return (chi*2)/(1+sqrt(1+alpha*alpha*tan2));

}
float D(float roughness, vec3 norm, vec3 halfV) {
    float NdotH = max(dot(norm, halfV), 0.0);
    float r1 = 1.0 / ( 4.0 * roughness * roughness * pow(NdotH, 4.0));
    float r2 = (NdotH * NdotH - 1.0) / (roughness * roughness * NdotH * NdotH);
    return r1 * exp(r2);
}
void main()
{
    float gamma = 2.2f;
    float roughnessValue = texture(glossTexture, TexCoord).r;
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0f, 0.8f, 1.0f)*4.0;

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(camPos-FragPos);
    vec3 halfVector = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);

    float NdotL = dot(norm, lightDir);

    float spec = 0;
    if(NdotL > 0.0) {
        spec = ( F(1.45, viewDir, halfVector) * G(viewDir,norm,halfVector,roughnessValue) * D(roughnessValue,norm,halfVector)) / (3.14151828 * dot(norm, viewDir) * dot(norm, lightDir));
    }
    vec3 specular = spec * lightColor;
    vec3 ambient = vec3(0.05);
    vec3 diffuse = (1 - texture(metalTexture, TexCoord).r) * diff * lightColor + ambient;
    vec3 finalcolor = (diffuse * pow(texture(diffuseTexture, TexCoord).rgb, vec3(gamma))) + specular;

    color = vec4(finalcolor, 1.0f);
    color.rgb = pow(color.rgb, vec3(1.0/gamma));

}
```

I know there are some unused values but that's because the shader isn't completed yet.

Comment: Tip: instead of manual gamma correction use an sRGB framebuffer. It is more correct (standard monitors work in sRGB, which is not a simple gamma at all).

Comment: @ybungalobill I'll implement it. Thanks!

Comment: What paper did you base your implementation on? Your G coefficient looks all wrong (in particular it shall not be dependent on roughness).

Comment: @ybungalobill I tried basing the partial geometry term (GGX) on the one from [Coding Labs](http://codinglabs.net/article_physically_based_rendering_cook_torrance.aspx).

Comment: Except that you are shading fragments that are away from the light source, it actually might be correct. I've independently implemented Cook-Torrance and for high values of roughness I get a similar effect near the terminator. Can you post the exact values of roughness, metalic, diffuse, etc... values you are using? For simplicity even use a solid texture.

Comment: @ybungalobill The diffuse value is #f02f34/`vec3(0.94, 0.18, 0.20)`, the metal value is 0 and the (average) roughness value is 0.215. But is the cutoff really supposed to look like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my independent implementation of Cook-Torrance based on Beckmann distribution:

```
layout(location = 0) in PerVertex
{
    special3 pos; // tangent to view
    vec2 texcoord;
    vec4 diffuse;
} IN;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 OUT;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_bump;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D u_raughness;

struct PerLight
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
};

layout(binding = 1) uniform lights_block
{
    int nlights;
    PerLight lights[4];
} LIGHTS;



float D(float m, float c) {
    float c2 = c*c, m2 = m*m, c2m2 = c2*m2;
    return exp((c2 - 1)/c2m2)/(3.14159*c2m2*c2);
}
float F(float R0, float NV) { return R0 + (1 - R0)*pow(1 - NV, 5); }
float G(float NL, float NV, float NH, float HV) { return min(1, 2*NH*min(NV, NL)/HV); }

void accumulate_light(special3 tangent, vec3 viewDir, float roughness, PerLight light, inout vec3 diffuse, inout vec3 specular)
{
    vec3 lightDir = quat_apply(tangent.q, light.position);

    if(lightDir.z > 0)
    {
        lightDir = normalize(lightDir);
        float NL = lightDir.z;
        diffuse += NL * light.color;

        float NV = viewDir.z;
        if(NV > 0)
        {
            vec3 halfDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
            float NH = halfDir.z;
            float HV = dot(halfDir, viewDir);
            specular += D(roughness, NH)*F(0.034, NV)*G(NL, NV, NH, HV)/(4*NV*NL) * light.color;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    special3 tangent = {
        vec3(0),
        texture(u_bump, IN.texcoord.xy)
    };

    tangent = special_mul(IN.pos, tangent);
    tangent = special_inverse(tangent);

    const vec3 viewDir = normalize(tangent.v);

    vec3 diffuse = vec3(0.05);
    vec3 specular = vec3(0);
    float raughness = max(0.215 + texture(u_raughness, IN.texcoord.xy).r - .5, 0.001);
    for(int i = 0; i < LIGHTS.nlights; ++i)
        accumulate_light(tangent, viewDir, raughness, LIGHTS.lights[i], diffuse, specular);

    OUT = vec4(diffuse*IN.diffuse.rgb + specular, IN.diffuse.a);
}
```

Here are the images I get:

[image: Perpendicular angle]

At a grazing angle you see a hard cutoff, but apparently this is how it is supposed to be for high roughness values:

[image: Grazing angle]

If I add a bump map then the effect isn't visible anymore:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason why this violent cutoff appears. All three of us in this thread did the same mistakes in our respective independent implementations. We forgot the area projection term, in the final lighting formula:
[image]

Applying it correctly fixes, this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

So in terms of your shader, that means:

`vec3 specular = spec * lightColor * NdotL;`

And same for diffuse (the ambient doesn't apply because it comes from all directions so separate diffuse and diffuse ambient)

*Source:* http://www.trentreed.net/blog/physically-based-shading-and-image-based-lighting/